# Android: Refreshing an action bar tab from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

In activity's action bar option menu there is an option to refresh current data in view. In my scenario I have an activity that displays 3 tabs using action bar tab and fragments. Only when a user clicks refresh should I go and fetch data again from server. So how do I tell the fragment inside the tab within the activity to refresh from the activity?

Answer (score 0):

Find the fragment in your `FragmentManager` and call a method on it, telling it to refresh. Use `getSelectedNavigationIndex()` on `ActionBar` to learn which is the selected tab.